# Report Studio Filtering Using Multiple Drop Down

Tags: report, reporting, cognos, activereports

I have a question regarding Cognos Report Studio/Active Report:

I'm creating a report that's being filtered by multiple (about 5) different drop down menus. Let's say the report is for a University, and the drop downs are to filter by College, Major, Gender, etc.

I want these drop downs to connect together for filtering data using all of them (if necessary).

I know how to use ONE drop down menu, and connecting it to the data deck containing charts and graphs.

However,

I'm having trouble understanding how to connect 2 or more drop downs together, and ultimately to the data deck.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. And I can provide any further details.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

You may try creating a parameterized report wherein you can set as many parameters as you want to and thereafter the data would be filtered/displayed on the basis of these parameters.

Please refer to the following documentation link wherein the same has been implementation has been discussed :
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR8Help/AR8_HelpOnlineEN/AddParameters.html

Regards,
Mohita